# Table Column Repeated Horizontally And Display The Value According

Tags: sql, sql-server

My Table Schema (table name is record)

```
ID int,

Name Varchar(100)
```

Looks Like

```
ID  Name
1   Mahesh
2   Mahendra
3   Kirti
4   Jatin
```

I want to show Records as below

```
Name        Name
Mahesh      Mahendra
Kirti       Jatin
```

Is it possible in SQL Server to return the data as above?

Comment: You want the names in columns, based on what criteria?

Comment: why you want to show like this and what purpose it serves ????

Comment: @Flimzy, I didn't get. But I want the values of field Name to shows like above... Sometime its a need to display your records by consolidated way to consume less page's height

Comment: @mohan, you can see the usage of page in above example if you display records vertical then it will consume height of page but if you consume it in my way then it will consume less height of page and you can display your imported data in very first page.....

Comment: So you want to display the output differently in your HTML? That's an HTML question, and has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: @user2741987 this is part of the application layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should be done in application layer, but if you insist(maybe legacy systems) you can add `ROW_NUMBER` and use simple grouping by integer division:**

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)-1
  FROM #tab
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN name END) AS Name1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN name END) AS Name2
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn /2;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414103)**</kbd>

This solution can be easily converted for more columns:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id)-1
  FROM #tab
)
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 0 THEN name END) AS Name1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 1 THEN name END) AS Name2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 3 = 2 THEN name END) AS Name3
FROM cte
GROUP BY rn /3;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414105)**</kbd>

Comment: this is part of the application/presentation layer

Comment: @lad2025, its really apreciated efforts, but I have incorrect syntax error near the keyword "with due to common table expression

Comment: @lad2025, my plus point to your Demo

Comment: @user2741987 Add semicolon before and after

Comment: @deterministicFail it is the part of application/presentation layer too.but in some case particularly data view horizontally it is not possible so that time such code will be useful

Comment: @user2741987 no, it is not, it is a design failure. Maybe it makes sense to your "particularly" case, but it is careless to leave it uncommented

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible in SQL Server to return the data as above?**

Yes, it can be done.

You have to define a rule that will be used to determine which names will be displayed on first column and which names on the second column.

Let's assume that the rule is: `columnNumber = 2 - rowNumber % 2` which works if you need the `Name` repeated only once. In other words the names on odd rows appear on first name column and names on even rows appear on second column.

```
with recordsWithRowNumbers as
(
    select   *
            ,ROW_NUMBER() over ( order by id ) as RowNumber
    FROM    records
),
oddRows AS
(
    select * from recordsWithRowNumbers where RowNumber % 2 = 1
),
evenRows AS
(
    select * from recordsWithRowNumbers where RowNumber % 2 = 0
)
SELECT  o.Name as Name1,
        e.Name as Name2
FROM    oddRows o
        left JOIN
        evenRows e on e.RowNumber = o.RowNumber + 1
```

A similar method can be used if you want to repeat the name column more than once.

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6416